# Why can't I establish a connection to the local oracle database from within the pre-built oracle virtual machine?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, java

I downloaded [DeveloperDaysVM2016-06-02_13.ova](http://download.oracle.com/otn/other/virtualbox/dd/DeveloperDaysVM2016-06-02_13.ova) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html and successfully loaded it into Virtual Box.

I logged in as "oracle" user and I can see the desktop.

From within the virtual machine, I opened Firefox and navigated to:

http://localhost:8080/ords/hrrest/employees/ and successfully received a list of employees in JSON format. So I know the database is up and running.

Now I am trying to connect to this database via the "ojdbc6.jar" Java connector/driver from Netbeans (see image below).  However,

when I enter in

username:hr
password:oracle
SID:orcl12c
URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl12c

I get an error message indicating

> "Unable to add connection. Cannot establish a connection to
>   jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl12c using
>   oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon
>   denied"

But this doesn't make any sense because I was able to successfully login from the terminal:

```
sqlplus hr

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jul 7 17:21:07 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: oracle
Last Successful login time: Thu Jul 07 2016 16:33:31 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Why can't I login via the java connector from netbeans?

I also checked

```
lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 07-JUL-2016 17:22:12

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                05-JUL-2016 16:48:08
Uptime                    2 days 0 hr. 34 min. 4 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           orcl12c
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/vbgeneric/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=vbgeneric)(PORT=8081))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl12c", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl12c" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl12c", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "orcl12c", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl12cXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl12c", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ords" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl12c", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
[oracle@vbgeneric oracle]$
```

So what am I doing wrong? Everything seems to be up and running correctly in this pre-built virtual machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the same story over and over again. Oracle uses the multitenant architecture in this VM and they set the environment variable `TWO_TASK`. This causes a lot of confusion.

When you connect as `sqlplus hr`, the value of `TWO_TASK` is automatically appended to the connection string, and you are connecting to `SERVICE_NAME=ORCL` and not `SID=ORCL12` or `SERVICE_NAME=ORCL12`. The user `hr` was created in the `ORCL` pluggable database. With `SID=ORCL12` or `SERVICE_NAME=ORCL12`, you connect to the root container, where this user does not exist, hence you receive the `ORA-01017` error.

[image]

So instead of the connection string:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl12c`

Use this for connecting:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl`

Note the `/orcl` instead of `:orcl12c`.

`:` specificies an instance connection (SID), while `/` speficies a service connection (SERVICE_NAME). You have to specify the service name when connecting to a pluggable database, because multiple pluggable databases share the same instance, and the name of the service is what differentiates them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string also needs to contain the username and password:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/oracle@localhost:1521:orcl12c
```

That should work OK.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I also tried to write java code similar to http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/ sample code and I am getting the exact same error in the stack trace.  Is there some service that needs to be enabled in oracle to connect remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Use the drop down menu:  Driver Name: menu, 
and pick/use Oracle Thin (Service Name).

(Instead of: Service ID (SID)).